# store Blog post as plain text in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose

I've programmed a blogging system with node js as the backend and mongodb for database purposes. So far so good.

I want to store the total blog post text in a field in mongodb using mongoose.

Of course I am getting the "key too large to index error" as fields bigger than 1024 bytes won't be indexed.

On average my blog post has a size of 5000-10000 bytes.

What is the best approach to store it in the database as there is no way to exceed the 1024 bytes limit to my knowledge.

Storing the Blog posts as plain text on the file system is no option to me as I need to be able to provide a blog post search on my blog.

I was thinking about spliting the blog post to several fields. is there any work around for my approach or is it just a silly approach of me as mongodb was not designed to store large text exceeding the 1024 bytes value per field?

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that it can't **index** that field. Make sure you're storing the post in a field that doesn't have an index.

Comment: how can I make a schema in mongoose that index all fields but skips only the "content" field which holds my blog post text? I literally searched for hours and couldn't find an answer that fits to my problem